# how to do jndi configuration inside karaf for activemq

Tags: activemq-classic, bundle, jndi, apache-karaf, karaf

I have installed activemq feature inside karaf now i am not getting how to  use karaf jms or jndi feature to connect osgi bundle(nothing but consumer class) with activemq which are running inside karaf .can any body help me..

### environment using-

Apache karaf 4.0.4
activeMQ 5.13.1

Thanks for your help in advance